# Taking slices from several images and stitching them together

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have several images like the one which can be seen below:

[image]

In all images the location of the two bars are always in the same position on the y axis. They only change intensity.

I would like to take a pixel row at a certain height on the y-axis of all images, stitch them together and display the resulting image.

So far i have the following in Matlab:

```
A = imread('image0000000351.pgm');
A = floor(A./16); % // transform back to 12 bit
[n m] = size(A);
B = A-400; % // remove background noise 
imagesc(B);
```

I'm a bit lost at this stage. How would i proceed to cut a slice on the y-axis for several images and stich them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take a slice out of an image you would just use normal range indexing. Assuming a multichannel color image,

```
C = B(startY:endY,:,:);
```

You don't say if the images are aligned along the X-axis or if they need to be adjusted, but if they're already aligned all you need to do from there is concatenate each new slice to the final image.

```
FinalImage = vertcat(FinalImage, C);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would do that outside Matlab in the shell, or by using the `system()` command and let ImageMagick do the cutting out of the strips of the images and the joining together of the strips to form a whole.

So, say you wanted 5 lines starting at scanline 600 from the top of all of your image files whose names match with `in*.png`, you could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Edit these as you wish
NLINES=5        # Extract 5 lines from each image
YOFFSET=600     # ... starting at 600th scanline from top

for f in in*png
do
   echo Extracting line from $f
   convert "$f" -crop 0x${NLINES}+0+${YOFFSET} +repage "strip-$f"
done

echo Joining strips
convert strip* -append result.png
```

I coloured your image red, green then blue and saved it 3 times as `inR.png`, `inG.png` and `inB.png` and ran the script and got this:

[image]

ImageMagick is equally happy with `PGM` files - just change the extensions in my script.